# How do I view gpu / h.264 block usage?

Tags: hardware, gpu, monitoring

Normaly I can get this infromation from psensor but on the pi the only monitors i have access to are cpu and ram usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `sudo vcdbg hist` and `sudo vcdbg reloc`.